# git push error. unpack-objects died of signal 7

Tags: git

[image]

I set up gitlab as git server and works well for months.

today, a repo cannot push to origin master. but pull is ok.

I have try as much as i can search from google.

add this config in ~/.gitconfig in both remote and local

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    packedGitLimit = 128m
    packedGitWindowsSize = 128m
[pack]
    windowMemory = 128m
    packSizeLimit = 128m
    deltaCacheSize = 128m
    threads = 1
```

try this command in local

```
git repack remote/origin/master
git gc
git fsck
```

but still not work.

Comment: Does a push work against a local clone? (instead  of pushing to the GitLab server) `git clone` your repo, `cd yournewclone`; `git reset --hard @~` (remove last commit), and try a `git push` from your local original repo to your new local clone, just to see if that works.